# Display a list of custom post types titles

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I´m displaying a list of custom post types using this code:

```
    <!-- List post types -->
    <?php $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'artworks_post',
        'title_li'=> __('')
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args ); 
    ?>
```

The problem is that I can´t control that list, is there other way to display a list of custom post type titles where I can control how it will make the markup?

Comment: I want to be able to add: rel="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" to the "a" of the item list

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular ol' [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<a rel="' .the_permalink(). '" href="' .the_permalink(). ' ">'. the_title() .'</a>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: in Which File we have to Write this Code. can you tell the Path of File?

Comment: It depends on your theme. If you put this code in the functions file, it won't do much. If you wrap it in a function and call that function in your theme somewhere, it will. If you put it in a page template, it will show up on any page with that page template.